# We are trying to persist logs in S3 using Kinesis firehose. However I would like to merge each stream of data into 1 big file. How would I do that?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, streaming

Should I be using lambda or use spark streaming to merge each incoming streaming file into 1 big file in s3. ?

- Thanks
  Sandip

Answer (score 1):

You can't really append files in S3, you would read in the entire file, add the new data and then write the file back out - either with a new name or the same name.

However, I don't think you really want to do this - sooner or later, unless you have a trivial amount of data coming in on firehose, your s3 file is going to be too big to be constantly reading, appending new text and sending back to s3 in an efficient and cost-efficient manner.

I would recommend you set the firehose limits to the longest time/largest size interval (to at least cut down on the number of files you get), and then re-think whatever processing you had in mind that makes you think you need to constantly merge everything into a single file.

Answer (score -1):

You will want to use an AWS Lambda to transfer your Kinesis Stream data to the Kinesis Firehose. From there, you can use Firehose to append the data to S3.

See the [AWS Big Data Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/persist-streaming-data-to-amazon-s3-using-amazon-kinesis-firehose-and-aws-lambda/) for a real-life example. The GitHub page provides a sample [KinesisToFirehose Lambda](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-big-data-blog/blob/master/aws-blog-firehose-lambda/kinesisFirehose/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/proserv/lambda/KinesisToFirehose.java).